# Aggregating mongo documents where one specific value is one group and rest are in the other group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have below structure of data in my mongo collection:

```
{app: 'app1', status: 'success', count: 5},
{app: 'app1', status: 'fail', count: 4},
{app: 'app1', status: 'blocked', count: 3},
{app: 'app1', status: 'transferred', count: 6},
...
```

There are more such documents, where each application can have multiple status( Not necessarily all of them). I want to count success status of all application in one group and all other status in second group, like below:

```
{app: 'app1', status: 'success', count: 5},
{app: 'app1', status: 'failed', count: 13},///4+3+6=13
```

How can I write an aggregate query for this? I am trying but unable to think of anything because here I have to separate 'success' from rest of the statuses.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$switch` in a `$group` to put all cases other than success into the default branch.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        app: "$app",
        status: {
          "$switch": {
            "branches": [
              {
                "case": {
                  $eq: [
                    "$status",
                    "success"
                  ]
                },
                "then": "success"
              }
            ],
            "default": "failed"
          }
        }
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": "$count"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IFjpELhNQWy)